Delay between trigger and execution of Azure Functions
I have an Azure functions (Pricing plan: Consumption plan Y1) that hosts an python endpoint that is used by the mobile application to check if a certain event have started. It connects to NoSql CosmosDB and gets the data then return it in body. In times it may recive a burst of calls (It cannot be cached before anybody asks).
I've decided to check how will the solution work under stress and hit it with around 100 calls in a short period of time (1-5 seconds). Each call took more time to finish, but I've noticed something strange as each call was waiting more and more between triggering and actual execution of first command. Some of them took more than 30 seconds. I've assumed there are just too much calls, but when I run a simpler function (one without call to any DB, just returning a json), each execution take around the same amount of time.
This brought me to conclusion that, the connection to DB might be a problem, but when I tried to measure how long does the retrival of data from DB takes it shows that it should not cause the problem. The main factor of how long the call is processed seems to be the delay between trigger and start of execution. The log below shows better what I mean.
Code:
@app.route(route="get_start_stop", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
def get_start_stop(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('get_start_stop - HTTP trigger')

    start_stop_tic = time.perf_counter()
    # retrival of data from database
    start_stop = repository_service.get_start_stop()
    start_stop_toc = time.perf_counter()
    logging.info(f'get_start_stop returned start: {start_stop.get("start")},'
             f'stop: {start_stop.get("stop")},'
             f'time of execution: {start_stop_toc - start_stop_tic:.6f} seconds')
    return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(start_stop), status_code=200)

Image of growth of execution time from jmeter:  https://i.sstatic.net/kZfYUQOb.png
Logs:
2024-05-08 20:42:13.033 Executing 'Functions.get_start_stop' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=f55d807c-1dfc-4b30-86d7-cb351d310dd2) Information
2024-05-08 20:42:31.179 get_start_stop - HTTP trigger Information
[...]
2024-05-08 20:42:31.314 get_start_stop returned start: 2024-04-10T22:00:00Z,stop: 2024-06-13T22:00:00Z,time of execution: 0.136382 seconds Information
2024-05-08 20:42:31.315 Executed 'Functions.get_start_stop' (Succeeded, Id=f55d807c-1dfc-4b30-86d7-cb351d310dd2, Duration=18282ms) Information

In first two lines you can see a delay of 18 seconds between trigger and execution of first command (logging.info('get_start_stop - HTTP trigger')). Retrival of data from DB only took 0.1 second. I've assumed that consumption plan automatically scales out (the Maximum Scale Out Limit is set to 200). So my questions are:

Why does the delay occur? Could you guide me what else should I check?
Does connection to DB have something to do with the delay? Or is it that this few more operations turn the tide and add up?
Is the scailing automatic? Can I check if the additional nodes are being created?



Why does the delay occur? Could you guide me what else should I check?

The delay is most likely caused by the scale-out operation. The API requests in a consumption plan are pooled, and a worker agent triggers scale out operations and distributes the requests accordingly. If you throw another 100 requests at the function just after all requests have completed, you will likely see better results, as the instance count will still be higher since the function will not have scaled-in yet.
As a means to best practice, also ensure that your function code is non-blocking. Make sure you use async/await, where applicable.

Does connection to DB have something to do with the delay? Or is it that this few more operations turn the tide and add up?

Concurrency will affect database performance, yes. But, depending on your Cosmos DB plan, and without knowing the amount of work required to complete your queries, it's hard to say whether this is the performance bottleneck.

Is the scailing automatic? Can I check if the additional nodes are being created?

It's part of the platform and so is automatic, yes.
You can monitor the number of instances of your Azure Function app that are running at any given moment through Azure Monitor. Azure Monitor provides insights into the performance and usage of your function app, including metrics related to instance count and resource utilization.
To view the number of instances:

Azure Portal: Navigate to your Azure Function app in the Azure Portal. Under the "Monitoring" section, select "Metrics". Here, you can select metrics such as "Function Execution Count" or "Function Invocation Rate" and filter by the specific function or function app to see the instance count.

Azure Monitor Metrics Explorer: You can also use the Metrics Explorer in Azure Monitor to query and visualize metrics related to your function app, including instance count. You can customize charts and queries to monitor the specific metrics you're interested in.

Azure CLI or PowerShell: You can use Azure CLI or PowerShell commands to retrieve metrics programmatically. For example, you can use the az monitor metrics list command to list metrics for your function app and retrieve the instance count.


